# R error when using write.xlsx with an object created with functions of 'dplyr'

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, xlsx

I´m having a problem when trying to write a data frame to an excel file using the function `write.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package. Though the problem only appears when the data frame was created with functions from the `dplyr` package. When I use base functions, there is no problem. Below is a minimal example.

First, the sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
month <- c('Julio','Diciembre','Diciembre','Agosto','Noviembre',
         'Diciembre', 'Junio','Septiembre','Agosto','Julio')

irrelevant_column <- rep(1,10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(irrelevant_column, month))
```

As I said, when I use base functions there is no problem:

```
month1  <- table(df$month, df$irrelevant_column)
month1  <- prop.table(month1  , 2)
month1  <- as.data.frame.matrix(month1  )
write.xlsx(month1 ,  file="month1.xlsx")
```

No error appears, but when I create a similar data frame with 'dplyr':

```
month2<- count(df, month)
month2<- mutate(month2, porc = n / sum(month2[, 2]))
month2<- as.data.frame.matrix(month2)
write.xlsx(month2,  file="month2.xlsx")
```

The following error message appears:

```
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  method setCellValue with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(value)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a solution for this, or is it that `xlsx` is not compatible with `dplyr`?

Comment: It works if you remove `month2<- as.data.frame.matrix(month2)`.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy ,)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : method setCellValue with signature (\[D)V not found when attempting write.xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394159/error-in-jcallcell-v-setcellvalue-value-method-setcellvalue-with-sig)

Answer (score 2):

ran into this issue and solved it using as.data.frame() to designate the tibble output from group_by() %>% summarize() as a df.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed with this solving using

```r
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(dataset), "name.xlsx")
```